# postgresql: Which Index isn't used in "select" query search

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance

I have two db servers on different machine, which own the same config file. I name them A & B, 600+M records in A (online), and 600M records in B (test).

Problem:

I create the same index on A and B, all of them is on table `tasks`, column `time`. When I make the same select search (`explain analyze select * from tasks order by time desc limit 1`) in A and B, the search in A never user indexscan, but B use, even I forbidden enable_seqscan on A.

Just like the index on A never exist! But `\d tasks` shows the time index exists in it.

TABLE INFO:

```
                                Table "public.tasks"
     Column     |     Type      |                     Modifiers                      
----------------+---------------+----------------------------------------------------
 id             | integer       | not null default nextval('tasks_id_seq'::regclass)
 taskid         | character(32) | not null
 time           | integer       | 
 threat         | integer       | 
Indexes:
    "tasks_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "tasks_taskid_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (taskid)
    "tasks_taskid_index" btree (taskid)
    "tasks_time_index" btree ("time")
Referenced by:
    TABLE "alert_detail" CONSTRAINT "alert_detail_taskid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (taskid) REFERENCES tasks(taskid) ON DELETE CASCADE
Triggers:
    after_del AFTER DELETE ON tasks FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE fileref_auto_decrease()
```

Query: (after " SET enable_seqscan = Off;" and "analyze tasks;")

```
# explain (analyze,buffers)  select * from tasks order by time desc limit 2;
                                                                   QUERY PLAN                                                                

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----
 Limit  (cost=10000729745.02..10000729745.02 rows=2 width=668) (actual time=20602.895..20602.896 rows=2 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=457 read=592336
   ->  Sort  (cost=10000729745.02..10000746864.02 rows=6847601 width=668) (actual time=20602.894..20602.895 rows=2 loops=1)
         Sort Key: "time"
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 27kB
         Buffers: shared hit=457 read=592336
         ->  Seq Scan on tasks  (cost=10000000000.00..10000661269.01 rows=6847601 width=668) (actual time=0.003..18939.268 rows=6847881 loops
=1)
               Buffers: shared hit=457 read=592336
 Planning time: 0.094 ms
 Execution time: 20602.930 ms
```

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes) and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: check the diff in all settings, not just index existence or `enable_seqscan `

Comment: thank you much, I'm sure that setting is the same. and I have added the table info and query with explain On the board.

Comment: `width=668` + `SELECT *` :: the optimiser may think it is cheaper to just scan + sort. Maybe it is right, or maybe your settings for random_page_cost and/or effective_cache_size are wrong. BTW: you have duplicate indexes on taskid.

Comment: total count of records in tasks is more than 6,000, 000. I think planner should choice index_scann, setting is the same with another, because I product the tow machine with the same script and copy the same file on the same os.

Comment: thank you for your "you have duplicate indexes on taskid" I not found it ^ _^

Comment: `600+M records in A (online), and 600M records in B (test).` that is not 6M. Maybe you are executing on a different machine? (the rowsize doesn't match either)

Comment: yeah, I'm so sorry for my bad english |||||

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve this issue, the reason probably is that the postgres in A has not enough of memory, it's ok after restart postgresql service. I think the load of B would be better than A